# Use foreach on ajax POST data received with comma seperating values

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm sure this is a simple solution so thank you in advance I just can't seem to find the correct solution for this.

I have a job board, currently I am working on the filtering system using ajax, jquery, and php. I have it set up so that when I click on a checkbox or multiple checkboxes it sends me the data, but currently it is sending me the data of multiple check boxes like so: 12,34. I am trying to separate these out using a foreach loop so that I can use these values independently for an sql statement, but as of right now it doesn't print anything.

This is my simple filter page:

```
<body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 class="text-center">Insert Checkbox values using Ajax Jquery in 
PHP</h3>  
                <div class="checkbox">  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_state_value" value="SD" />SD 
<br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_state_value" value="NE" />NE 
<br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_state_value" value="IA" />IA 
<br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_state_value" value="CA" />CA 
<br />                      
                </div> 
                
                <div class="checkbox">  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="SD" />SD <br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="NE" />NE <br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="IA" />IA <br />  
                     <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="CA" />CA <br />                      
                </div> 
                <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" 
id="submit">Submit</button>  
                <br />  
                <div id="result"></div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           
           var state = []; 
            $('.get_state_value').each(function(){  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))  
                {  
                     state.push($(this).val());  
                }  
           }); 
           
            var specialty = [];  
           $('.get_value').each(function(){  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))  
                {  
                     specialty.push($(this).val());  
                }  
           });  
           
           state = state.toString();  
           specialty = specialty.toString();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"display.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{state:state, specialty:specialty},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

This is the important part of my ajax file:

```
$stateString = json_decode($_POST['state'], true);
 if(isset($_POST["state"]))  
 {  
     $state = null;
     if(!empty($_POST['state']))
     {
        $stateString = json_encode($_POST['state'], true);
        foreach ($stateString as  $value) 
            {
         $statew .= "AND jobstate = '".$value."' OR ";
            }
         $state = substr($statew, 0, -4);   
     }
     else
     {
         $state = '';
     };
```

I have tried to use json_decode thinking this would make the data more readable for the foreach loop, I have also tried to encode thinking hey why not, I've tried without either, but I just cannot figure out what is making it not display anything when I try to echo out  the $state variable. I'm sure I am doing something silly/a little wrong I just don't know what that is nor do I have anyone to ask that could help. Thank you SO community for letting me ask this silly question and thank you for any guidance of what to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just ship the data off to your PHP as arrays?
Dont do this:

```
state = state.toString();  
specialty = specialty.toString();
```

instead send the arrays to your PHP, then:

```
 if(isset($_POST["state"]))  
 {  
     $state = null;
     if(!empty($_POST['state']))
     {
        // just iterate the array

        foreach ($_POST['state'] as  $value) 
            {
         $statew .= "AND jobstate = '".$value."' OR ";
            }
         $state = substr($statew, 0, -4);   
     }
     else
     {
         $state = '';
     };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just needed another set of eyes on my issue!